# How to color the dots in scatter3 based on data from 4th variable?

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have 3D coordinates (x,y,z) of channels located inside the brain. I am plotting them on the brain map using scatter3 function to obtain the picture below (now the coordinates are not really true, but it doesn't matter for now):
[image: Brain picture with channels]
The colour now is just randomly assigned, but I would like to colour the each dot on my scatter3 based on data from 4th variable. The 4th variable has information about the number of signals detected in that channel. For example, I have 80 channels with X, Y, Z coordinates (80x3) and one more variable N with number of signals (80x1). How is it possible to colour my 80 channels based on N? I would like to make visually interpretable with a colorbar nearby - for example, the darker the point the higher the number of signals were detected in that channel.

Now I have only this:

```
scatter3(sw_chs_coords(:,2), sw_chs_coords(:,1), sw_chs_coords(:,3), []); 

xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
hold on
view(0, 0)
```

Can you help me please with that?

Comment: Just use the `C` parameter: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#d120e1108499

Comment: C parameter takes the color coding as an input (for example, [0 0 1] for blue), but I don't have it. I have the number of signals detected in each channel. It is a good ideas, but how can I construct the color for each dot?

Comment: Look at the third bullet point: *"If C is a vector with length equal to the length of X, Y, and Z, then the values in C are linearly mapped to the colors in the current colormap. "* i.e. just pass ghat number of signals vector directly to `C`

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds just as the 5th input of [`scatter3`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html)

> scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C) draws each circle with the color specified by C.
>
> - If C is a RGB triplet or character vector or string containing a    color name, then all circles are plotted with the specified color.
> - If C is a three column matrix with the number of rows in C equal to    the length of X, Y, and Z, then each row of C specifies an RGB color
>   value for the corresponding circle.
> - If C is a vector with length equal to the length of X, Y, and Z, then    the values in C are linearly mapped to the colors in the
>   current    colormap.

So you can either specify RGB values (that is a 3x1 array in [0 1] or x/256 of a normal RGB value) or you provide just another information vector and the thing is set to a [colormap](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) representing the continuous value in the vector.